# как исправить java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError при запуске в отладке?

Tags: android, yandex-metrika-api, firebaseanalytics

возникает ошибка при запуске в отладке
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

классы в ошибке бывают разные
com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
androidx.work.impl.background.gcm.GcmScheduler
com.yandex.metrica.rtm.client.ExceptionProcessor

были ответы на похожие вопросы. Пробовал rebild, clear, удалял .gradle, а галочки Instant Run в новой версии Android Studio нет.

как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
удалил .idea
удалил .gradle
удалил gradle
Проект перестал запускаться в AS
закрыл AS
подставил gradle из другого проекта
запустил AS при включенном интернете
2 минуты что то обновилось  
проект запустился как новенький, летает не нарадуюсь.
```